# What is the best method to filter content using checkboxes in PHP?

Tags: php, checkbox

I have the following checkboxes:

> ```
> [] Jackets
> [] Jeans
> [] T-Shirts
> [] Shoes
> [submit button]
> ```

When the user, for example, checks [x] Jackets and [x] T-shirts and clicks [submit button], the form will send a post request to itself. Then, somehow a dynamic query is generated based on the check boxes selected, and then only the selected categories will be queried..then displayed on the page.

The problem that I am having is trying to create the query dynamically after the post request.

Comment: I think what your trying to do is going to be involving heavy ajax.

Comment: Is there no way to just create it using a POST..then extracting info that way?

Comment: I mean you can use POST, but why would you use post? What if someone wants to bookmark the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// options
$options = array(
    'Jackets' => 'jackets', 
    'Jeans' => 'jeans', 
    'T-Shirts' => 't_shirts', 
    'Shoes' => 'shoes'
);

// create sql where
$sql_where = array('1');
foreach ($options as $option)
{
    if (isset($_POST[$option])) $sql_where[] = "field = '$option'";
}

// query data
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE " . implode(' AND ', $sql_where));

// create html
$sql_where = array('1');
foreach ($options as $name => $option)
{
    ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="<?= $option?>" id="<?= $option?>" value="1" />
        <label for="<?= $option?>"><?= $name?></label>
    <?
}
```

Comment: Wow, this might be what I need! Thanks!

Comment: You can also generate the input from the array. (Updated)

Answer (score 1):

Use "HTML Array"..

```
<input type="checkbox" name="item[]" value="1" />
...
<input type="checkbox" name="item[]" value="4" />
```

Than in PHP fetch it:

```
if ($_POST["item"][1])
...
if ($_POST["item"][6])
```

Check this: http://davidwalsh.name/checkbox-form-input-arrays

Comment: Thanks, will be sure to check this out.

Answer (score 0):

One method, not sure if it's the best, is to create your query part by part.

Imagine you want to select (using SQL) all membres of a table :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `clothes`"
```

Then add your request restrictions :

```
$options = array(
    'jackets', 
    'jeans', 
    't_shirts', 
    'shoes'
);

$firstClause = true;
foreach ($options as $option)
{
    if (isset($_POST[$option])) 
    {
        if ($firstClause)
        {
            $sql .= " WHERE ";
            $firstClause = false;
        }
        else
        {
            $sql .= " OR ";
        }
        $sql .= "field = '$option'";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about the following

Expanding on what grafa said:

```
$checked = $_POST['item'];
$query_where = "";
$N = count($checked);
for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
{
  if($i=0)
    $query_where = $query_where . "WHERE field = '". $checked[$i] . "'";
  else
    $query_where = $query_where . "AND field = '". $checked[$i] . "'";
}
```

And then just add this to the rest of your select query, just remember to check if the values are set etc.